# How to Unit Testing RuntimeType

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

```
[Test]
// arrange 
// ...
// act
var result = (Car) service.GetCar(req);

// assert
Assert.AreEqual(result, typeof(Car));
```

But I'm getting following error

```
Expected: <Models.Car> (Car)    
But was:  <Models.Car> (RuntimeType)
```

I tried to change assert to use `Is.InstanceOf`:

```
Assert.AreEqual(result, Is.InstanceOf<Car>());
```

But I'm still getting error, this time

```
Expected: <Models.Car>
But was:  <<instanceof Models.Car>>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to prove here? You already know that `GetCar` returns a reference of a particular type, because that's how the .NET type system works. You know that the object it returns is of type Car or one of its derived types, or the code wouldn't compile. If you want to guarantee that only `Car` is returned and never one of its derived types, you could mark it as `sealed` which will prevent deriving everywhere. What are you really trying to achieve with this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following means that you want to compare object and type, while you want to compare type of the object: `Assert.AreEqual(result, typeof(Car));`

You could use: `Assert.AreEqual(result.GetType(), typeof(Car));`, but I'm not sure if this will work.

But the best option is to *try* casting and failing if cast is not successfull:

```
try
{
    var result = (Car) service.GetCar(req);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

or you could use `Assert.ThrowsException()` method to check if exception been thrown, but it's not straightforwards, as previous method.

```
Action action = () => { var result = (Car) service.GetCar(req); };
Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(action);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cast the result of `service.GetCar(req)`. This would work:

```
var result = service.GetCar(req);

Assert.IsInstanceOf<Car>(result);
```

Or, as an alternative, use:

```
var result = service.GetCar(req);

Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<Car>());
```